# Fireworks or confetti with modal dialog on page load

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm looking for sample code that combines a confetti or fireworks animation with a Vue or Vuetify modal dialog.  When the page loads I need to splash a message to the user that they have just qualified for a pay increase. With a modal dialog, it's hard to miss the message and the animation just makes them feel like they finally reached that next level, time to celebrate!

Comment: Something like [vue-confetti](https://github.com/alexandermendes/vue-confetti) would probably work for you.

Comment: I'm trying to use this one:  https://www.iprodev.com/confetti-animation-javascript/ as it has ribbons and a different look.  However, I cannot seem to get it to work with Vue.

Comment: Here is my confetti animation. You can easily use it in any vue component like normal javascript 
https://codepen.io/duannx/pen/XoJvYN